Semantic Role Labeling for English Newspaper
I am doing reserch on Newspaper headlines that are written in English. As part of my reserch, I want to labeling the semantic roles (SRL) of the entities in the headlines, and I would like to use some-sort of NLP technique to do this.
What are some modern sematic role labeling NLP models or ways to do this (using Python).
I looked into using AllenNLP and other resourcces, but many of the models seem **outdated. **

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
